# how to anchor widgets at the bottom of a frame using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm in the process of learning Tkinter. I'm using customTkinter to set up a sidebar with the needed widgets. all of them are located in a widget_frame. Whats the appropriate way to make all widgets be anchored at the bottom of a frame instead of the top:

```
class Watermarker(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1200x907')
        self.title('PyMark')

        self.columnconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.my_image = Image.open('default-placeholder.png')
        self.image_ratio = self.my_image.size[0] / self.my_image.size[1]
        self.resized_image_tk = None

        self.widget_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.widget_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Make button_frame resizable

        # button frame widgets:
        self.path_field_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.widget_frame, text='File Path: ', font=('verdana', 12))
        self.path_field_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', padx=15)

        self.path_field = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.widget_frame)
        self.path_field.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.browse_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.widget_frame, text='Browse Files',
                                                     command=self.load_file_name)
        self.browse_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(10, 0), padx=10, sticky='w')

        self.watermark_text_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.widget_frame, text='Watermark Text:',
                                                           font=('verdana', 12), anchor='w')
        self.watermark_text_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w', padx=15)

        self.watermark_text = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.widget_frame)
        self.watermark_text.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 10), columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        self.add_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.widget_frame, text='Add Watermark', command=self.add_watermark)
        self.add_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, sticky='w')

        self.save_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.widget_frame, text='Save', command=self.add_watermark)
        self.save_button.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, sticky='e')

        self.widget_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self, background='#333333', bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.show_full_image)
```

One way i think of fixing it is by making another frame, adding the widget_frame to it and using sticky to place it at the bottom, but the result looks off.

Comment: I thnk the way you mentioned is the easier way.  What does *"the result looks off"* means? Any image showing it?

Comment: tried adding a sidebar frame, but cant seem to figure out how to actually move the widget frame to the bottom. currently i have it set up as:

self.sidebar = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
self.sidebar.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

self.widget_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.sidebar)
self.widget_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

self.sidebar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
self.widget_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s')

here is the current window: https://i.imgur.com/A87TTZh.png

github repo if helps: https://github.com/Ernestas-t/PyMark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in your question, you can create another frame as the sidebar frame and put `widget_frame` at the bottom of this frame:

```py
...
# create an outer frame to hold the widget_frame
self.sidebar = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
self.sidebar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.sidebar.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# create widget_frame as child of sidebar frame
self.widget_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.sidebar, fg_color="transparent")
self.widget_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Make button_frame resizable
...
#self.widget_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
# put widget_frame at the bottom
self.widget_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", pady=10)
...
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! the "side" argument is what i was looking for, and the fg_color="transparent" is a neat trick as well. That answers my question :)